# Multiple / compound return types

Tags: typescript

Does this

```
function foo(): () => void | string
```

mean, that

a) the function `foo` may return a string, or another function which doesn't return anything; or

b) the function `foo` returns another function, which in turn may or may not return a string?

Also, how do you correctly and clearly denote the other option (whichever one is incorrect)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function foo(): () => void | string` : foo is a function that has no input params and it will return another function that the result of that will be void or string

`function foo(): void | string` : foo is a function that has no input params and it will return void or string

`function foo(): (() => void) | string` : foo is a function that has no input params and it will return string or another function that returns void

Comment: Thank you! And I assume one could also put the return type in the first example

    `function foo(): () => void | string`

into parentheses to make it clearer, like so:

    `function foo(): () => (void | string)`

Answer (score 2):

`() => void | string` is the type of a function that may or may not return a string, which doesn't seem very useful since a function returning a string is already assignable to `() => void`.

If you wanted "either a function, or a string", you should use brackets: `(() => void) | string`, the same way you would use brackets in any other case where you want to use operators not in order of precedence.

Answer (score 1):

It means (b)

```
/**
 * The function foo returns another function,
 * which in turn may or may not return a string.
 */
function foo(): () => void | string;

// example implementation
function foo(): () => void | string {
  return () => {
    if (Math.random() % 2 === 0) {
      return "bar";
    }
  };
}
```

Here is how you would define (a)

```
/**
 * The function foo may return a string,
 * or another function which doesn't return anything.
 */
function foo2(): (() => void) | string;

// example implementation
function foo2(): (() => void) | string {
  if (Math.random() % 2 === 0) {
    return "bar";
  }

  return () => {};
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Would accept this as another answer if I could.

Comment: @Drejk No problem... there are lots of points to go around. :-)